# Docker Compose file will not mount

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to mount a file into my container in my `docker-compose.yaml` file like so:

```
version: "3"
services:
  data-service:
    volumes:
      - /path/to/file.js:/usr/src/app/file.js
```

But I made a mistake.  The first time I did a `docker-compose up`, the file did not exist on my host machine.  Whatever happened during that run made some permanent change somewhere because I placed the file in the correct location, but when I do a `docker-compose up`, I still get the following error:

```
ERROR: for data-service  Cannot start service data-service: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/path/to/file.js\\\" to rootfs \\\/var/lib/docker/overlay2/{really long hash}/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/{same hash}/merged/usr/src/app/file.js\\\ caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

Here's the interesting bit: The docker-compose file works fine for my whole team except for me and one other team member who made the mistake of running it before the file existed the first time.

Since adding the file doesn't fix the problem, it appears that the problem is somehow getting "cached" (for lack of a better term).  I thought maybe pruning my volumes would help (in case a spurious volume w/ the name of the file path had been created).  But it did not help.

Anyone have any ideas what could cause the problem to persist for us?

Comment: On your host system, is `/path/to/file.js` a directory (after running it the first time)?  Do you have a separate `volumes:` declaration mounting some volume on to the container's `/usr/src/app`?

Comment: No, `/path/to/file.js` is a file and not a directory (I had that very same thought, but alas ... it is a file).  And no, I don't have a separate `volumes:` declaration mounting something to `usr/src/app` ... I double-checked.